# JConsole/VisualVM Failed To connect to GridGain node With IOException

Tags: java, gridgain

When I connect to GridGain node using JConsole or VisualVM, I get IOException.

How to overcome this?

Comment: What is the exception, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the hostname correctly resolves to the host address.

Run the command:

```
hostname -i
```

If it reports `127.0.0.1`, JConsole/VisualVM would not be able to connect through JMX to the JVM running on that Linux machine. To fix this issue, edit `/etc/hosts` such that the hostname resolves to the host address.

You can also add system property to GridGain: `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname>`